# How to stop scrapy from overriding CSV export file after every crawl

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently, I use scrapy to crawl through multiple pages of a webpage and export the data to a CSV file. Each day, the spider crawls through the pages and saves the data; however, it will write over the data from the previous days. I was wondering how I could program the pipeline so that it just writes to CSV in the same file starting at the end of the file. This way I can save all my previous scraped data in one place.

Comment: Need to see some code before we can fix your code!

Answer (score 0):

generally just change the parameter in your open file routine to append

change

```
f = open('filename.txt','w')
```

to

```
f = open('filename.txt','a')
```

Of course if we could see your original code it would help us to be more specific.